# How can I change URL halfway through the function in rvest?

Tags: r, web-scraping, rvest

I wrote this function to scrape a lyrics website using rvest:

```
library(rvest)
library(tidyverse)
library(magrittr)
library(scales)
library(lubridate)

songscrape <- function(x) {
  url <- paste0("https://www.azlyrics.com/", substring(x, 1, 1),"/",x, ".html")
  artist <- x
  
  SongsListScrapper <- function(x) { 
    page <- x
    songs <- page %>% 
      read_html() %>% 
      html_nodes(xpath = "/html/body/div[2]/div/div[2]/div[4]/div/a") %>% 
      html_text() %>% 
      as.data.frame()
    
    
    chart <- cbind(songs)
    names(chart) <- c("Songs")
    chart <- as.tibble(chart)
    return(chart)
  }
  
  SongsList <- map_df(url, SongsListScrapper)
  SongsList
  
  SongsList %<>%
    mutate(
      Songs = as.character(Songs) 
      ,Songs = gsub("[[:punct:]]", "", Songs) 
      ,Songs = tolower(Songs) 
      ,Songs = gsub(" ", "", Songs) 
    )
  
  SongsList$Songs
  
  #Scrape Lyrics 
  
  wipe_html <- function(str_html) { 
    gsub("<.*?>", "", str_html)
  }
  
  lyrics2 <- c()
  albums2 <- c()
  number <- 1
  
  for(i in seq_along(SongsList$Songs)) { 
    for_url_name <- SongsList$Songs[i]
    
    
    #clean name
    for_url_name <- tolower(gsub("[[:punct:]]\\s", "", for_url_name))
    #create url
    paste_url <- paste0("https://www.azlyrics.com/lyrics/", artist,"/", for_url_name, ".html")
    
    #open connection to url 
    for_html_code <-read_html(paste_url)
    for_lyrics <- html_node(for_html_code, xpath = "/html/body/div[2]/div/div[2]/div[5]")
    for_albums <- html_node(for_html_code, xpath = "/html/body/div[2]/div/div[2]/div[11]/div[1]/b")
    for_lyrics <- wipe_html(for_lyrics)
    for_albums <- wipe_html(for_albums)
    lyrics2[number] <- for_lyrics
    albums2[number] <- for_albums
    
    number <- number +1
    
    show(paste0(for_url_name, " scrape complete!"))
    
    Sys.sleep(10)
  }
  
  songs2 <- cbind(lyrics2, albums2) %>% as.data.frame()
  songs2$albums2 <-  gsub("[[:punct:]]", "", songs$albums2)
  
  return(songs2)
}
```

This function takes in the input of the artist name and applied it to the `url` variable and then scrapes the associated pages.

However, I've run into a problem scraping for the artist `ironwine`. Their usual link structure is `https://www.azlyrics.com/lyrics/ironwine/songname.html` but as you can see on their song list page [here](https://www.azlyrics.com/i/ironwine.html), after the album 'Years to Burn', their link structure changes to `https://www.azlyrics.com/lyrics/calexico/songname.html`.

The only change is the artist name variable, which is input to the function.

This happens for those 6 songs after which it is back to `ironwine`.

How can I accommodate for this change so that the function doesn't stop midway?

The `xpath` for that div is `/html/body/div[2]/div/div[2]/div[4]/div[180]` so I've tried inserting this:

```
#number is updated at the end of the loop, so number = 180 should be this song. 
if(number >= 180 && <=186) { 
artist = "calexico"
}
```

which should in theory change the url. However this doesn't happen. Can someone tell me how to fix this?

Comment: Even if someone can explain to me where `tryCatch` or `possibly` would go in this code, it would be a massive help, and do me a lot of good in the long run too! I don't know where to put it.

Comment: You have assumed that the artist for all associated pages is the same as the input artist. This edge case is probably not the only one as azlyrics seem to restrict the url to one artist in case of a coproduction. If possible, scrape the artist name when you scrape the songs of an input artist.

Comment: @Love Tätting I don't know how that is possible, since the long is first scraped by using the input artist and all songs, regardless of being co-produced or not, are listed under that artist. The page with the lyrics is where the distinction may be but to get there we need to know the URL, which is being read incorrectly. Instead, would you be able to tell me how to just ignore the 404 errors and write in `Na` for all such errors?